# Replacing specific characters from a matched string in a regular expression where I don't know the number of instances of the match

Tags: php, regex

My regular expression use is a little on the rusty side so here's my current head scratcher:

I have a long string containing a whole load of field names and values. I've already got it sorted to place all of these into an associative array using the first entry as my key and the second as my value etc.

There are however some values that consist of multiple entries which mess up the array.

My input data looks like this:

```
field_name_1|my value for 1|field_name_2|aaabbb sdsdsd|field_name_3|1232|0930|2245|field_name_4|value for 4
```

I'm creating my array by splitting on the | characters and this works fine. The problem is that the sets of 4 digits for field_name_3 are being treated as keys in my array as well.

What I need to do is to replace the | characters between those 4 digit entries with a space character to effectively combine them into a single value as far as the code is concerned.

The end result array should contain something like:

```
  field_name_1 => my value for 1
  field_name_2 => aaabbb sdsdsd
  field_name_3 => 1232 0930 2245
  field_name_4 => value for 4
```

A couple of further notes:
There are many fields before and after these samples ones.
There could be any number of sets of 4 digits to apply the change to.

I've got the following which is doing the right sort of things for 2 sets but it isn't directly scaleable to any number of sets.

```
<?php
    
    $data = "field_name_1|value 1|field_name_2|0624|0935|field_name_3|value 3";
    
    $result = preg_replace("/(\d{4,4})\|(\d{4,4})/","$1 $2",$data);
    
    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a lookahead here:

```
$data = "field_name_1|value 1|field_name_2|0624|0935|field_name_3|value 3";
$result = preg_replace("/(\d{4})\|(?=\d{4})/", "$1 ", $data);
echo $result;
```

This prints:

```
field_name_1|value 1|field_name_2|0624 0935|field_name_3|value 3
```

The idea is to match only one 4 digit sequence at a time, along with a pipe, replacing that match by the same number followed by a space.  The problem with your current pattern is that matches *and* consumes two sets of digits.  So for the following input:

```
field_name_1|value 1|field_name_2|0624|0935|1234|field_name_3|value 3
```

Your current output would be:

```
field_name_1|value 1|field_name_2|0624 0935|1234|field_name_3|value 3
```

Note that the second pipe is not being replaced.

Comment: That is perfect for me. Thanks so much for that. Am I right in assuming that in this case the ?= you used is the lookahead you mentioned? So it's matching any set of four digits and | so long as it's followed by another 4 digits?

Comment: @ChimpTamer Yes, `(?=\d{4})` is a lookahead, but the important thing to note here is that it matches but does not _consume_.  The issue with your current pattern is that it _consumes_ the second four digit number, and once a number is consumed it can't be used again.

Comment: Ahh right. That makes sense. Thanks again. I've popped your solution into my main code and it works perfectly straight away. I'll read some more on the consume part as well for future ref. Your help here is much appreciated.